# How to record video with voice of Google+ hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

I’ll be doing a Hangout with 9 other people and I would like to record the whole thing, so others can see it later.

How do I record a Google+ hangout session (both video and audio)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very late answer, but here it goes: you could use the [Hangouts On Air](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/onair.html) feature.

> Well, with Hangouts On Air, you can share and *record your live discussions* and performances with everyone!

(Emphasis added by me.)

[Source](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/onair.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html) was a fairly useful tool to screen capture with audio, when I've used it previously.

> Simple and FREE, Jing is the perfect way to enhance your fast-paced online conversations. Create images and videos of what you see on your computer screen, then share them instantly!
>
> **Use Jing to…**
>
> - Take Screenshots: Capture an image of what you see on your computer screen
> - Record Screencasts: Record up to 5 minutes of onscreen video